# Frequency table of continuous variable in SQL?

Tags: sql, hiveql, impala

I have a *continuous* variable SQL table:

```
    x
1   622.108
2   622.189
3   622.048
4   622.758
5   622.191
6   622.677
7   622.598
8   622.020
9   621.228
10  622.690
...
```

and I try to get a simple frequency table, e.g. with 3 buckets, like this:

```
bucket                  n
[621.228-621.738[       1
[621.738-622.248[       5
[622.248-622.758]       4
```

Seems easy but I cannot manage to make it in SQL (I am running it on a Cloudera Impala engine).
I have looked into `dense_rank()` or `ntile()` without success.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions to divide the range into three equal parts and then use arithmetic:

```
select min_x + range * (row_number() over (order by min(x)) - 1) as bucket_hi,
       min_x + range * row_number() over (order by min(x)) as bucket_hi,
       count(*)
from (select t.*,
             min(x) over () as min_x,
             max(x) over () as max_x,
             0.000001 + max(x) over () - min(x) over () as range
      from t
     ) t
group by floor((x - min_x) / range)), min_x, range
```

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two problems with your question:

1. You have not provided any code to show us what you have tried. It really is good sometimes to just work out the problem yourself. Nevertheless, I found the problem interesting and decided to play.
2. Your range blocks overlap. If, for example, you were to have the value 621.738 in your list, which bucket would contain it? [621.228-*621.738*] or [*621.738*-622.248]?

There are also at least three problems with my answer, so I don't expect you to accept this. However, maybe it will get you started. Hopefully, this disclaimer will keep me from getting down voted. :-)

1. The answer is in T-SQL. Sorry, it's what I have to work with.
2. The answer is not generic. It always creates three and only three buckets.
3. It only works if the data type limits the result to 3 decimal places.

Remember, this is only one possible solution, and in my mind a very weak one at that.

With those disclaimers, here's what I wrote:

```
SELECT
       '[' + STR( RANGES.RANGESTART, 7, 3 )
           + ' - '
           + STR( RANGES.RANGEEND, 7, 3 ) + ']'    AS 'BUCKET'
      ,COUNT(*)                                    AS 'N'
  FROM
       ( SELECT
                VALS.MINVAL + (CAST( CNT.INC AS DECIMAL(7,3) ) * VALS.RANGEWIDTH) AS 'RANGESTART'
               ,CASE WHEN CNT.INC < 2
                     THEN VALS.MINVAL + (CAST( CNT.INC + 1 AS DECIMAL(7,3) ) * VALS.RANGEWIDTH) - 0.001
                     ELSE VALS.MINVAL + (CAST( CNT.INC + 1 AS DECIMAL(7,3) ) * VALS.RANGEWIDTH)
                END AS 'RANGEEND'
            FROM
                ( SELECT
                         MIN(CURVAL)                     AS 'MINVAL'
                        ,MAX(CURVAL)                     AS 'MAXVAL'
                        ,(MAX(CURVAL) - MIN(CURVAL)) / 3 AS 'RANGEWIDTH'
                    FROM
                        MYVALUE ) VALS
                        CROSS JOIN (VALUES (0), (1), (2) ) CNT(INC)
        ) RANGES
        INNER JOIN MYVALUE V
                ON V.CURVAL BETWEEN RANGES.RANGESTART AND RANGES.RANGEEND
GROUP BY
        RANGES.RANGESTART
       ,RANGES.RANGEEND
ORDER BY 1
;
```

In the above, your values would be in the CURVAL column of the MYVALUE table.

Good luck. I hope this helps you on your way.